# Distinct columns having the max date value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table:

```
LpOpenTradeId   LPSource    SymbolId    Volume  CreatedUser CreatedDate
1               2           1           10.00   2           2015-12-11 00:00:00.000
2               2           4           12.00   2           2015-12-11 00:00:00.000
3               2           1           10.00   2           2015-12-11 10:53:00.000
4               2           3           1.00    2           2015-12-11 18:03:14.676
5               2           5           1.00    2           2015-12-14 09:38:33.691
6               2           3           2.00    2           2015-12-14 09:39:30.305
7               2           4           13.00   2           2015-12-14 09:43:13.916
8               3           1           15.00   2           2015-12-11 10:53:00.000
```

I want to select the distinct LPSource and SymbolId columns with the Volumes having max CreatedDates. I mean the target result set is:

```
            LPSource    SymbolId    Volume              CreatedDate
            2           1           10.00               2015-12-11 10:53:00.000
            2           4           13.00               2015-12-14 09:43:13.916
            2           3           2.00                2015-12-14 09:39:30.305
            2           5           1.00                2015-12-14 09:38:33.691
            3           1           15.00               2015-12-11 10:53:00.000
```

How can I express myself to have this resultset in T-SQL?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT LPSource, SymbolId, Volume, CreatedDate
FROM (
SELECT LPSource, SymbolId, Volume, CreatedDate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LPSource, SymbolId 
                          ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

In case of `CreatedDate` ties, i.e. more than one records sharing the same maximum   `CreatedDate` value within the same `LPSource, SymbolId` partition, the above query will randomly select one record. You can use `RANK` to select all records in such a case.

Comment: I think you have forgotten the paranthesis of ROW_NUMBER(). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @anilca Glad I was able to help. Yes you are right, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if no other row with same `LPSource`/`SymbolId` has (1) a later `CreatedDate`, or (2) same `CreatedDate` but a higher `Volume`.

```
select distinct LPSource, SymbolId, Volume, CreatedDate
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.LPSource = t1.LPSource
                    and t2.SymbolId = t1.SymbolId
                    and (t2.CreatedDate > t1.CreatedDate
                         or (t2.CreatedDate = t1.CreatedDate and
                             t2.volume > t1.volume))
```

Comment: Does not ensure that you only get one. OP wanted distinct columns, so i assume that even in case of max-ties there should be only one row returned for each LPSource,SymbolId.

Comment: Yes, perhaps there can be CreatedDate duplicates. SELECT DISTINCT will remove duplicates.

Comment: If the CreateDate is duplicated and the volume is different, a distinct will not fix anything. It will still return both rows

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tabel1','U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Tabel1
END
CREATE TABLE Tabel1 (LpOpenTradeId INT
,LPSource INT   
,SymbolId INT    
,Volume DECIMAL(10,2)  
,CreatedUser INT
,CreatedDate DATETIME2
)
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (1,2,1,10,2,'2015-12-11 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (2,2,4,12,2,'2015-12-11 00:00:00.000');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (3,2,1,10,2,'2015-12-11 10:53:00.000');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (4,2,3,1,2,'2015-12-11 18:03:14.676');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (5,2,5,1,2,'2015-12-14 09:38:33.691');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (6,2,3,2,2,'2015-12-14 09:39:30.305');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (7,2,4,13,2,'2015-12-14 09:43:13.916');
INSERT INTO Tabel1 VALUES (8,3,1,15,2,'2015-12-11 10:53:00.000');

    SELECT DISTINCT t1.LPSource
,t1.SymbolId
,t1.Volume
,t1.CreatedDate 
FROM Tabel1 t1
    JOIN (
        SELECT LPSource
            ,SymbolId
            ,MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
        FROM Tabel1
        GROUP BY LPSource
            ,SymbolId
        ) t2 on t2.LPSource = t1.LPSource AND t2.SymbolId = t1.SymbolId AND t2.CreatedDate = t1.CreatedDate
```

The JOIN part :

```
SELECT LPSource
        ,SymbolId
        ,MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
    FROM Tabel1
    GROUP BY LPSource
        ,SymbolId
```

get's the latest LPSource and SymbolId. You then JOIN your initial table with all the columns in this temporary table (t2) giving you the result needed.t1.LPSource, t1.SymbolId, t1.Volume, t1.CreatedDate